# REST: book a room example fits architecture?

Tags: rest

Is my approach to book a room in a conference hall:

`PUT: api/v1/rooms/book/1`

`GET: api/v1/rooms/1`

```
POST: api/v1/rooms
```

fits REST architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your approach, you define the "book" as a resource - which is fine in restful perspective.

But - the http method will be better to be a "POST" for this situation, as you create a new instance of the "book" resource (this is more restfuly in case you consider "book" as a resource, which you are).
and it basically means that the POST method should include the room_id in the request body rather than `book/1`

**Rooms resource:**

`GET: api/v1/rooms/books/` - All the booking

`POST: api/v1/rooms/books` - book new (room_id in body) - there's a better restful approach in the next resource:

**Book resource**

`GET: api/v1/rooms/<room_id>/books/` - Get room `room_id` books

`POST: api/v1/rooms/1/book` book new (book id in url resource, more restful than rhe rooms resource example)

**a book resource**

`PUT api/v1/rooms/<room_id>/books/<book_id>` - Update book information

`GET api/v1/rooms/<room_id>/books/<book_id>` - Retrieve book information

Answer (score 0):

As you clearly asked for whether your design fits the REST architecture:

Actually the form of the URI is not of relevance in a REST architecture. Clients will use link relation strings to lookup a URI dynamically. I.e. if a client wants to progress to the next page it will look for a URI annotated with `next` (see registered link relations at [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml)). In case there is no fitting link-relation yet present at IANA's registry you can either attempt to register one or fall back to an approach outlined by [Web linking extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8288#section-2.1.2), which uses a URI that does not necessarily need to target an actual resource but just defines the relation within an own namespace. Technically, each relation builds up a triple (subject, predicate, object), similar to an ontology, where the subject is always the current resource and object always the target resource and the predicate being the link relation name or verb in that triple. A URI can further have multiple link-relations assigned, i.e. `create-form https://acme.org/rel/book-room` where the first `create-form` link relation indicates that the resource will provide a form to create a new resource and the second one, the Web linking extension one, will indicate to clients that support this kind of relation that a room can be booked using the underlying URI. This whole indirection allows a server to change its URI scheme anytime it wants to and clients will still be able to make further requests.

Please note though that resources in a REST architecture never have [types](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html) that are significant to clients. This is similar to the Web we interact on a daily basis. Even though we visit different HTML pages that represent car models, shopping products and what not, the content returned by the server is still a HTML page containing data that could also be expressed in other representation formats. HTML after all just defines which tags are valid within the scope of the HTML document (syntax) received as well what each of these tags expresses (semantics). Through content-type negotiation both client and server can and should agree on a representation format both understand and can operate on.

In case a server expects some client input an approach very similar to traditional Web surfing done by humans can and should be used. Humans usually interact with [HTML based Web-Forms](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html). Here, the form teaches a client about the properties a resource supports, the target URI to send the request to, the HTTP operation to use as well as (most often implicitly given) the media type to use for marshalling the payload to before transmitting the request. This way clients learn new features a server has for a resource automatically.

The [intent of a REST architecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_TH-Y78tt4&t=860s) is besides the decoupling of clients from servers also the freedom of evolution on the server side so that new features can be introduced without breaking any clients. As HTTP and URI define a standard interface that is widely supported by languages and frameworks, the core focus needs to be put on the actual media-type exchanged between client and servers. This is the coupling part between both of them. The overall question here should not be which media-type to support but how many different ones as with each one you support you just increase the likelihood of your application being able to interact with peers in that architecture.

So your actual question whether your URI design fits a REST architecture can't be answered actually as, as mentioned throughout this post, REST is more than meaningful URIs or which HTTP operation you perform on a URI. From a true REST architecture standpoint your URIs are fine as far as they don't violate with the [URI specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986). In general, one of the best advice to give on designing peers in a REST architecture is to model the whole interaction as if you'd design a browser-based Web interaction and than transfer the same concepts onto a more general application layer using link support through [HAL JSON](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-08) or [JSON Hyper-Schema](http://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/json-schema-hypermedia.html) or form-support through [HAL forms](https://rwcbook.github.io/hal-forms/) or [ION](https://ionspec.org/#forms) in case you prefer exchanging JSON payloads.